# How to only show only the first element in foreach loop binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout-2.2.0.js. I have created a foreach loop binding on observableArray and i want to show only first element in the array. For this i tried : (both not work)

First

```
        <!-- ko foreach: myArray -->
          <span data-bind="text: $data, visible: $index == 0"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

Second

```
        <span data-bind="text: myArray[0]"></span>
```

I know that there is a `_destroy` property which if set on any array element than that element will be excluded from the foreach loop binding in UI. But i dont want to use this in my case. Can anybody please tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you avoid doing the foreach, and just do something like `<span data-bind="text: myArray()[0], visible: true"></span>`

Comment: If myArray is an observable, don't forget you have to call it like a function to access the indices.  Also,  have you run it in Chrome and checked the console (f12)?  What error is it giving you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are on the right track. But you have forgot to put out the `()` in both of your examples.

`myArray` an observable array and `$index` is an observable so they are functions so you need to call them as functions with `()` to get their values inside expressions.

So the correct bindings are:

```
<!-- ko foreach: myArray -->
    <span data-bind="text: $data, visible: $index() == 0"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And

```
<span data-bind="text: myArray()[0]"></span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTkyX/).

Note: if you really just want to display the first item then you should prefer the `text: myArray()[0]` version because it is much cleaner there what you are trying to do.